# Show that the solution of a 2nd order ODE exists locally, is unique and can be continued so long as y and y' remains bounded.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> $1.$ Show that if $g\in C^1(\mathbb R)$ and $f\in C(\mathbb R)$ then the solution of $$y''+f(y)y'+g(y)=0,\quad y(t_0)=A,\quad y'(t_0)=B$$exists locally, is unique and can be continued so long as $y$ and $y'$ remain bounded.

I have hints the from the professor for this problem. I would like to share those with you. 
[image][image]
Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Have you tried the hints?

Comment: yup, I tried to convert the 2nd order ODE to 1st order ODE, after that I tried proving that its a Lipschitz in x just like the hint say. However, I am not able to get it correctly. That's why I thought i seek help from the experts. It would really be helpful if you can help me out.